# Is it possible to install a openvms image (iso) on VirtualBox?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, openvms

Whanted to get a openvms dev enviroment, where could use it to learn the basic command's to get feel for it without worrying about breaking anything.

1. So whanted to know if its possible to install a openvms iso image in Virtual Box
2. In case its possible where could get a openvms image or needed first to get installation cds and from those generate the iso?
3. if the cds are needed is there some online store that can be bought or the price is only afordable for companies?

only making inqueries to see if its possible and feasible, other wise gona give up the ideia of having a development enviroment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what do you know so far, and what do you have so far?
Do you know that OpenVMS has a 40+ year history, was originally written for the (32 bit) VAX platform, ported to 64-bit Alpha (30+ years ago), then ported to Itanium and X86 (64 bit).
That X86 port will boot natively and you may want to ue VMware, Virtualbox or similar - within the current constraints and offeringg - visit vmssoftware.com for details.

For initial learning I recommend to just  to use an Alpha or VAX emulator.
Those could run on a virtual machine, but there is no good reason.
Just run as process on whatever laptop/server your have running Windows (and some Linux options I think).

There are are several emulators out there, both free and commercial - google is your friend.
I happen to like/use FreeAXP for Alpha running under 64 bit windows - just Google.

There is no Itanium emulator.

Do you have access to the software distribution somehow?

For starters, why even bother trying to get your own system?
Just timeshare to get a feel for it.
For example SSH to decuserve.org [184.168.131.241 - ooops: 104.207.199.162 ] - ask for an account - presto!
Other timeshare options are available - and very valid to learn the basics (file system, editors, compilers,...)

Good luck!
Hein.

Comment: thanks @Hein for the answer gona follow your sugestions, only starting found a link for a book where starting to read https://flylib.com/books/en/2.928.1.5/1/ but first wanted to have enviroment to start applying the basic concepts, thanks again for the feedback.

Comment: have tried to register in decuserver.org as you stated also following https://raymii.org/s/blog/My_first_OpenVMS.html and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.vms/A-wfT4DLxK8 either by telnet or ssh but keep getting 'connection time out', can you confirm if its down?
Other timeshare options are available: can't seem to find alternatives by searching in google can you indicate what keyworks you use for seaching in google? thanks in advance

Comment: I'm in right now - I think I gave an old address - sorry.this works now: 104.207.199.162 (eisner.decus.org)

Comment: so this command should work: ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss REGISTRATION@eisner.decus.org  
 
but have tried that as also in the blog and keep getting ssh: connector to host eisner.decus.org port 22: Connection timed out by command line or by PuTTY

Comment: Dunno - works fine for me with PuTTY and blank password when using REGISTRATION 

login as: REGISTRATION
Pre-authentication banner message from server:
|
<snip>
| To subscribe to DECUServe       please login under -> Username REGISTRATION
<snip>
End of banner message from server
REGISTRATION@eisner.decus.org's password:

Registration for DECUServe Subscriptions is open to anyone who  ....

Comment: yes found a solution for now, seems some network related probleam as states in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.vms/A-wfT4DLxK8, where @Simon Clubley pointed that maybe related to "VSI firewall".

Comment: Whilst its ALWAYS good to want to learn - can someone please fill in the missing number for OpenVMS?  Worldwide Microsoft Windows systems - 1billion, worldwide Android systems - 4billion, worldwide Apple systems - 2billion   Worldwide OpenVMS systems ?  <= Hein, please ?

Comment: Richard, my mother always told me that if I have nothing nice to say then I should say nothing. With that in mind I'll refuse to directly answer your question. :-). I'm sure the current OpenVMS Software owner (VSI) belief there are enough servers today to support their business model. I hope they are right for them, but personally very much doubt it. I only hear about people trying to get off, but that's perhaps only due to the particular customers I run into.